# Run paros on one machine, use it from another

Tags: proxy

How do I run paros proxy on one machine (X) and use it from another(Y)? 
Details:

- On X, in Tools/Options/Local Proxy, I've set address to 
  "127.0.0.1 192.168.0.2", and 192.168.0.2 is X's LAN address.
- On X itself, "telnet 127.0.0.1 8080" works, but 
  "telnet 192.168.0.2 8080" fails.
- On Y, "telnet 192.168.0.2 8080" fails.
- On X, I ran "/etc/init.d/iptables off", so I don't think this is a 
  firewall issue.
- Can I make paros log unsuccessful connection attempts?

I'm using Fedora 11 if that helps. I'll try an ssh tunnel next, but it 
shouldn't be necessary?

EDIT: OK, even the ssh tunnel didn't work. Here's what I did:

- From Y, "ssh -L 8079:X:8080 user@X"
- From Y, "telnet 127.0.0.1 8079". Result:

> ```
> Trying 127.0.0.1...
> Connected to localhost.
> Escape character is '^]'.
> Connection closed by foreign host.
> ```

- On the terminal where I did the "ssh" (on Y, now logged into X), I turned on -vvv for ssh and this happens:

```
Connection to port 8079 forwarding to 192.168.0.2 port 8080 requested.
debug2: fd 9 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: fd 9 is O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 9 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 3: new [direct-tcpip]
channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
debug1: channel 3: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 8079 for 192.168.0.2 port 8080, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 64087, nchannels 4
debug3: channel 3: status: The following connections are open:
  #2 client-session (t4 r0 i0/0 o0/0 fd 6/7 cfd -1)
  #3 direct-tcpip: listening port 8079 for 192.168.0.2 port 8080, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 64087 (t3 r-1 i0/0 o0/0 fd 9/9 cfd -1)

debug3: channel 3: close_fds r 9 w 9 e -1 c -1
```

EDIT: I've worked around the problem:

```
ssh -L 8079:127.0.0.1:8080 user@192.168.0.2
ssh -L 8079:192.168.0.2:8080 user@192.168.0.2
```

Of the two lines above, the first one works, the second one does not.

Comment: This suggests that Paros is only bound to loopback. There's an option when opening a socket indicating whether you want to allow remote connections. Fiddler, for instance, has an option in the UI for this.

Comment: OK, I'm not sure how to set this option for paros. I thought tweaking "Tools/Options/Local Proxy" would help, but it doesn't.